# Push item with interfaces on typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, interface

I need some help about interfaces in typescript

I have 3 interface:

```
export interface HomeMenu {
    [name: string]: MenuItem;
}

export interface MenuItem {
    title: string;
    route: string;
    homeMenu?: HomeMenu;
}

export interface Menu {
    homeMenu: HomeMenu;
}
```

Now i do this :

```
var json: Menu = {
    "homeMenu": {
        "aname1": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        },
        "aname2": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute",
            "homeMenu": {
                "aname21": {
                    "title": "text",
                    "route": "myroute"
                },
                "aname22": {
                    "title": "text",
                    "route": "myroute"
                }
            }
        },
        "aname3": {
            "title": "text",
            "route": "myroute"
        }
    }
}
json.homeMenu["aname2"].title = "myTitle";
```

But now how I can push a new item in the HomeMenu ? I tried to extend the HomeMenu interfaces with Array but I have an error about the index signature, Array want a number for Index(name) and not a string
 
I have checked the Typescript, some post and i haven't found an answer
Or maybe another solution to have a push function on homeMenu object ?
If someone can help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
json.homeMenu["aname4"] = {
    title: "title 4",
    route: "route4"
};
```